# Object may be Null error on typescript function

Tags: typescript, algorithm, function, debugging, null

Hey I am new to type script and got a Object may be null error in a function. The function is supposed to take in two LinkedLists which represent numbers (Every digit in the list is its own node), and add them returning a different Linked list. Can someone explain to me why I am getting this error?

This is the error

```
Line 33: Char 12: error TS2531: Object is possibly 'null'.
Line 33: Char 35: error TS2531: Object is possibly 'null'.
Line 35: Char 24: error TS2531: Object is possibly 'null'.
Line 36: Char 24: error TS2531: Object is possibly 'null'.
```

This is the function

```
// Definition for singly-linked list.
// class ListNode {
//    val: number
//    next: ListNode | null
//    constructor(val?: number, next?: ListNode | null) {
//        this.val = (val===undefined ? 0 : val)
//        this.next = (next===undefined ? null : next)
//    }
//}
//

function addTwoNumbers(l1: ListNode | null, l2: ListNode | null): ListNode | null {
    let carry = 0;

    let cNode1 : ListNode | null = l1;
    let cNode2 : ListNode | null = l2;
    let returnNode : ListNode | null= new ListNode(0 , null); 
    let cNode3 : ListNode | null =  returnNode; 


    while(cNode3 != null){
        let cVal1 = 0; 
        let cVal2 = 0; 
        if(cNode1 != null)  cVal1 = cNode1.val;
        if(cNode2 != null)  cVal2 = cNode2.val; 
    
        let cVal = (cVal1 + cVal2 + carry);  
        let resultingVal = cVal % 10;
        carry = Math.floor(cVal / 10); 
        cNode3.val = resultingVal;
    
        if(cNode1.next != null || cNode2.next != null || carry > 0){
             cNode3.next  =  new ListNode(0 , null); 
             cNode1  = cNode1.next;
             cNode2  = cNode2.next;
        }
    
         cNode3 = cNode3.next;
    }

    return returnNode; 
};
```

Line 33 is the following statement:

```
if(cNode1.next != null || cNode2.next != null || carry > 0){
```

Comment: Have you tried running that code?  What happens at runtime if you call `addTwoNumbers(null, null)`?

Comment: Are you new to JavaScript as well, or do you understand JavaScript well but not TypeScript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In line 33 you wrote:

```
if(cNode1.next != null || cNode2.next != null || carry > 0){
```

meaning, you trying to access next in cNode1, but it can be null. Same for cNode2. You should check if they are null before checking if one of their properties are null:

```
if((cNode1 && cNode1.next != null) || (cNode2 && cNode2.next != null) || carry > 0){
```

Or, if your environment supports it, you can use the new optional chaining operator (`?.`), which checks if the object is not null or undefined, and only if it is not one of those, it will try to access the properties:

```
if(cNode1?.next != null || cNode2?.next != null || carry > 0){
```

Comment: Thank you this helped I had to do the same for the statements in the if block